# Equivalent notions of the differential on a manifold. Why are they equivalent?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I would like to know how one sees the equality between these two notions of the differential:

$\mathbf{v}_p[f]=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\mathbf{p}+t\mathbf{v})|_{t=0}$

and

$df(\mathbf{v})=\sum_j{v^j(p)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}(p)$.

Here
$df:M^n_p \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbf p + t \mathbf v$ on a (non-flat) manifold? If you're working with component addition in a chart then this is just multivariable calculus and Faraad's answer is essentially correct, but you should be careful - this addition will depend on the chart you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the chain rule,

$$ \frac{d}{dt} f(c(t)) = \nabla f(c(t)) \cdot c'(t)$$

In your problem $c(t) = p+tv$.

Comment: This is not in enough detail for me.I do not know what is $\nabla$, and how your equality follows.

Comment: $$\nabla f = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}\right)$$ And my equality follows from the chain rule. I'm pretty sure they aren't asking you to prove the chain rule here since that's not something you can do on the spot i.e it wouldn't be good textbook question.